# sailsjs access associations in full response object in afterDestroy

Tags: hook, sails.js, lifecycle, waterline

When using the `DELETE` blueprint, in the `afterDestroy` hook, the `destroyedRecord` returned DOES NOT contain `associations`. However, the `res`ponse sent DOES contain the `associations`.

Is there a way to access these through `afterDestroy`?

Basically, the scenario is that we want to send out emails to users when a meeting gets canceled. Calling `DELETE - /meeting/5` gives you back the full `Meeting` including the associated `Users`, but you cannot get the users through `afterDestroy`.

Comment: how is meeting associated with the users?

Comment: `Meeting` is in a `many-to-many` association with `User`